Derivative of a matrix to a vector
In a new preject, the following equation is designed according to some meanings, where $\mathbf{A}^j\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$, $\mathbf{Q}_{j:}\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times k}$ and $\mathbf{L}_{:j}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$. Now I want to take the derivative of $\mathbf{Q}_{j:}$ and $\mathbf{L}_{:j}$, but I found different computations online. How can I solve such problem?
$$
\sum_{j=1}^M{\parallel}\mathbf{A}^{j}-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{Q}_{j:}^{T}\mathbf{L}_{:j}^{T}\parallel _{F}^{2}
$$
How can I get the right results? How to look at its derivation in a more understandable way? I also found the article "Matrix Calculus" on Wikipedia, but it lacks matrix-vector derivative.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\Ak{A^{k}}
\def\F{{\cal F}}
\def\A{A^{j}}
\def\lk{L_{:k}}
\def\qk{Q_{k:}^T}
\def\l{L_{:j}}
\def\q{Q_{j:}^T}
\def\green#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k\ne j}\:\Big\|B\,\qk\lk^T-\Ak\Big\|^2_F}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k\ne j}\:\Big\|B\,\qk\lk^T-\Ak\Big\|^2_F}
\def\u{\underline}
\def\RSk{\red{\Sk}}
$Contrary to what you might think, you don't really need any matrix-by-vector derivatives. Instead, you need to calculate the derivative of
a$\;{\u{\sf scalar}}$-valued norm with respect to one of its vector arguments.
First separate the objective function $\F\ $ into the $j$-indexed terms
and $\red{\rm\ all\ the\ other\ }$ terms.
$$\eqalign{
\F
 &= \Big\|B\,\q\l^T-\A\Big\|^2_F \;\;+\;\; \RSk \\
 &= \LR{B\,\q\l^T-\A}:\LR{B\,\q\l^T-\A}  \;\;+\;\; \RSk 
\quad\quad\; \\
}$$
Then calculate the gradient with respect to
the ${\sf\ column\ vector}\;\green{\q}$
$$\eqalign{
d\F
 &= \LR{B\;\green{d\q}\;\l^T}:\LR{B\,\q\l^T-\A} 
  + \LR{B\,\q\l^T-\A}:\LR{B\;\green{d\q}\;\l^T}
\;+\; \red{\large\emptyset} \\
 &= 2\LR{B\,\q\l^T-\A}:\LR{B\;\green{d\q}\;\l^T} \\
 &= 2B^T\LR{B\,\q\l^T-\A}\l:\green{d\q} \\
 &= \LR{2\|\l\|^2B^TB\,\q \;-\; 2B^T\A\l}:\green{d\q} \\
\frac{\p\F}{\p\q}
 &= 2\|\l\|^2B^TB\,\q \;-\; 2B^T\A\l \\
}$$
where a colon denotes the matrix inner product, i.e.
$\,X:Y = \operatorname{Tr}\LR{X^TY}$
The calculation of the gradient wrt $\,\l\,$ is very similar.
